# Parse binary content of the xlsx file on .net project

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, binary, xlsx

I have read throw `fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer` *.xlsx* file on the clientside. After that, I send it to the `WCF` service endpoint. The question is how to parse data from binary content on the server side? Do some libraries able to work with binary data instead of reading of a `xlsx` file from server environment? I use `WCF` service on the server. Thanks everyone for your suggestions!

Comment: Can you post your WCF endpoint method signature? Does it take a `byte[]`? You can load files from `MemoryStream`, but to write the necessary code, I'd need to know the types being sent to the WCF service.

Comment: I take a model with some props. One of them `Data` which contains `xlsx` file data and it has `byte[]` type.

Comment: _[Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Comment: If _"Do **some libraries** able to work with binary data instead of reading of a xlsx file from server environment? "_ isn't asking for libs (directly or indirectly) I don't know what is.   This is backed-up by the mere mention of the library _EPPlus_ in the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) since it's designed for server-side excel work.

To load from `MemoryStream`, use the following code:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(paramByteArray);
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
{
    //do something with the excel file
    package.Save();
}
```

Let me know if you have any issues getting it set up.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Michael, i will check it as soon as possible :)